# bs-timepicker does not have default value

Tags: angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my timepicker, however it does not show a dafault value. I am new to angularjs or bootstrap. I really appreciate your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('myProject').controller('Timepicker_{{ field.id_for_label }}', function($scope) {
            $scope.selectedTime = new Date("{{ field.value }}");
    });
</script>


<div class="form-group"
     ng-controller="Timepicker_{{ field.id_for_label }}">
     <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{ field.errors }}
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               ng-model="selectedTime"
               data-time-format="HH:mm"
               data-length="1"
               bs-timepicker
               data-autoclose="1"
               name="{{ field.name }}"
               >
    </div>
</div>
```

but when i delete bs-timepicker, it would show the default value which is selectedTime, however the timepicker will not be working

Comment: please provide as jsfiddle

Comment: open bs-timepicker js  file search default date in that file you can find something related to that one